# Core data: Transient values dirty object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm using transient values to provide some data within my application. The trouble is, as soon as these values are calculated, it dirties my Managed Objects, reporting that a re-save is necessary.

Is there anyway to prevent transient values from marking an object as dirty if there are no actual changes to the object graph.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this awesome post on transient properties](http://www.2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/transient_properties.html) in core data. It explains things far better than I can in this short space, plus I'm still getting my head around this!

This guy recommends using an IsValid flag and a Snapshot ivar to deal with this issue, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Could you declare the fields as unmanaged properties in your data model class (i.e. they are defined in the source code, but not included in the data model)?